# LINQ to DataSet, error in getting char field

Tags: c#, linq

```
var dadproductlist = from dgdproduct in dadData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
select new DeliveryAdjustmentProduct
{
    AdjustmentQuantity = dgdproduct.Field<int>("AdjustedQty"),
    AdjustmentType = dgdproduct.Field<char>("AdjustmentType").ToString(),
    DeliveredDate = dgdproduct.Field<DateTime>("ExpectedDate"),
    ProductCode = dgdproduct.Field<int>("ProductNum").ToString(),
    RevisedQuantity = dgdproduct.Field<int>("RevisedOrderQty"),
    SupplierId = dgdproduct.Field<int>("SupplierId").ToString(),
    TrailerId = "Pradeep"
};
```

I have written the above query to get a charecter field, its failing with `"Specified Cast Not Valid"`.

Comment: Definition of DeliveryAdjustmentProduct is required for us to inspect types of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have written the above query to get a charecter field, its failing
>   with "Specified Cast Not Valid"

If you are getting the data from database, then `CHAR` maps to `string` in C#. So try:

```
AdjustmentType = dgdproduct.Field<string>("AdjustmentType"),
```

instead of

```
AdjustmentType = dgdproduct.Field<char>("AdjustmentType").ToString(),
```

You may modify the type of `AdjustmentType`, or you try getting the first character from the string to be assigned to your `char` type `AdjustmentType` like:

`AdjustmentType = dgdproduct.Field<string>("AdjustmentType")[0]`

*(But the above only assumes that there is atleast a single character in the returned* string)